# I'm looking for an SMD diode in a (small) haystack, hearing aid repair

Tags: surface-mount, reverse-engineering, low-noise-amplifier

[image: hearing aid, batt on R, wires on top are to earpiece]

It works, but it buzzes through the earpiece if you turn up the volume much, I'd like to do some signal tracing, but first I'd like a schematic. I found one using 3 NPN transistors that might be close, but it has a diode for AGC that I can't find on my device. Either I don't recognize an SMD diode when I see one, or it's not there and my schematic is not applicable, and I need to find a drawing with just the transistors/resistors,& caps that are here. [image: the black thing's the chargeport] I need a diagram that's in the ballpark, as an aide to drawing one from the actual UUT. Then I drag out the 'scope.

Comment: It looks fairly simple to reverse engineer it.

Comment: what do you mean by `it buzzes`?

Comment: Buzz on electret mic’s is common when the common mode gain exists from unbalanced hum ingress from line E-field.  Try shielded earpiece cable with shield to battery 0V at one end only. http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Signal_Processing/Hearing_aid_the_4th.html and maybe a bigger low ESR cap across battery.

Comment: What is "haystack" referring to? If it's a brand name shouldn't it be capitalised to show that? Or is haystack a type of hearing aid feature?

Answer (score 3):

There is no diode onboard the circuit board, so the schematic you found is not applicable to this device.

Comment: OK, good. we're making progress, thanks. I'll try these suggestions, thanks for that promising diagram, Tony!